# What speed is 'fast' and 'faster' in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player, playback, video-playback

VLC isn't very informative in its playback speed designations.

Any idea as to which playback speed each adjective refers to?

Comment: If you show the Status Bar (View menu) you can find the play speed there.  This will allow you to try each one and see what the effect is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Result

- Faster (fine): 1.1×
- Faster: 1.5×
- Slower (fine): 0.9×
- Slower: 0.6×

**Update**: As of December 2017, neither "faster" nor "slower" seems to produce a fixed amount of change in speed (for example, if one presses "faster" five times, the sequence of speeds it goes through is 1.5x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 8x, 16x).

#### References

Pressing <kbd>[</kbd> to slow down and <kbd>]</kbd> to speed up displays ±0.1 the previous speed as large text in the top right.

Comment: In VLC 2.2.4 on Windows, I needed to choose `View` > `Status Bar`, and then I could see in the bottom right of the screen "1.80x" (or other number) as I used `[` and `]` to adjust playback speed. Thanks.

Comment: `[` or `]` must be used with some other keys. Is that so? Pressing just them while the video is running, doesn't change anything.

Comment: @AJ.S Works for me in VLC 2.2.2 under XFCE/Ubuntu